# Where is my vim color scheme coming from?

Tags: vim, colors, fortran

When I edit a Fortran file with vim on my iMac it uses a very nice color scheme. I would like to send this color scheme file to a friend, but I cannot find where it is coming from.

In vim the :colorscheme command lists "default".

The default.vim file in /usr/share/vim/vim73/colors has the following non comment lines:

```
hi clear Normal
set bg&
hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif
let colors_name = "default"
```

I have tested all of the color schemes in /usr/share/vim/vim73/colors and none of them are the one which vim is using.

My vimrc file contains the following non comment lines:

```
set modelines=0 
set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=2     " more powerful backspacing
au BufWrite /private/tmp/crontab.* set nowritebackup
au BufWrite /private/etc/pw.* set nowritebackup
:let fortran_free_source=1
:hi link fortranTab NONE
:syntax on
:highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=black
```

So where is this very nice color scheme coming from?

Comment: The colors are probably coming from the color-scheme of your terminal. What terminal are you using?

Comment: The default might be in syntax/syncolor.vim

Answer (score 0):

You are using the vim default colorscheme, so there is no file.  The defaults are baked in and you see that the file `defaults.vim` is just clearing certain things so they fall back to the default and resetting the syntax highlighting to defaults.  The default syntax highlighting colors are your terminal colors.  Your terminal emulator provides a 16 color palette (by default, it can however go up to 256 colors) and vim references its colors from this palette.  To send him your color scheme, you need to send him your terminal palette.

If you are using Terminal.app, you can see your color palette in *Terminal->Preferences->Settings* and the 16 color palette for each theme are the colors under "ANSI Colors".  If you are using xterm or another X terminal emulator the colors are typically specified in a `.Xresources` or `.Xdefaults` file with the form:

```
*color0:  rgb:2E/34/36
*color1:  rgb:CC/00/00
*color2:  rgb:4E/9A/06
*color3:  rgb:C4/A0/00
*color4:  rgb:00/00/FF
*color5:  rgb:74/4E/7A
*color6:  rgb:06/98/9A
*color7:  rgb:FF/FF/FF
*color8:  rgb:55/57/53
*color9:  rgb:EF/29/29
*color10: rgb:8A/E2/34
*color11: rgb:FC/E9/4F
*color12: rgb:72/9F/CF
*color13: rgb:AD/7F/A8
*color14: rgb:59/BC/D9
*color15: rgb:FF/FF/FF
```

and can be queried from the command line with `xrdb -q`.